# Unable to start MongoDB shell for mongos daemon

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to setup a sharded mongodb cluster using 4 solaris-11 servers which are on the same rack. The following sharded config is being attempted:

- Server A : Replica set 1(rs1)
- Server B : Replica Set 2(rs2)
- Server C : Configuration Server
- Server D : Sharding Router

#

On Server A, rs1 has been set up as follows:
mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs1 --dbpath "/mongo/datadb"

Now the rs1 configuration in mongo shell:

> config =
>   {
>       _id:"rs1",
>       members:
>       [
>           { _id:0, host:"Server A IP:27017" },
>       ]
>   }
>   rs.initiate( config )
>
> rs.conf()
>
> rs.status()

On Server B , rs2 has been similarly configured.

#

On Server C, the config server has been configured as follows:

mongod --configsvr --port 37017 --dbpath "/rpool/mongo/datadb"

#

Now on Server D, I am running mongos using the following :

mongos --port 27017 --configdb rs1/'Server C IP':37017

When I am trying to open mongo Shell on server D to add the shards using the mongos port and connect to mongos, I am unable to do so. The following error is thrown :

**./mongo --port 27017 --host 'Server C '

MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://'Server C ip':27017/
2017-11-09T11:21:51.666+0000 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to :27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-11-09T11:21:51.686+0000 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 'Server C ip':27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed**

When I tried to debug, I found the port 27017 on Server C to be in 'BOUND' state:

**netstat -an |grep 27017
      *.27017              *.*                  0      0  128000      0 BOUND**

**'Server ip' stream-ord server ip' 0000000000000000 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**

Shouldn't mongos occupy this port in Listening mode? Can someone help me in solving this?

Is there any issue with the configuration?